# Enums beginning with digits

Tags: java, enums, formatting

I have a list of commands from a legacy system that I'm enumerating as enums. They're almost all 3 uppercase characters [A-Z], but two of them are 3 digit numbers.

For the sake of example, let's say they're {FOO, BAR, BAZ, QUX, 007, 999}.

I'm trying to find a naming convention that won't cause me or anyone else headaches down the line. These values will likely be converted at some point between Java, JSON, and **shudders** Excel.

This is what I have at the moment.

```
public enum SystemXCommands {
    _007 ("007"),
    _999 ("999"),
    FOO,
    BAR,
    BAZ,
    QUZ;

    //The exact formatting of this command used in SystemX 
    String code;

    SystemXCommands(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    SystemXCommands() {
        this.code = this.name();
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if I should be worried about a leading underscore causing issues with format conversions. If so, is there a better convention in this sort of situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how Java naming can affect JSON serialization/deserialization. The token in JSON (or "element name" if you wish) is a string and can be "_007" as well as "007" or "BAZ". Also I don't see how can it lead to any difficulties with Excel.

**Conclusion:** You have normal name and should not worry about it.

By the way, following approach has potential errors:

```
this.code = this.name();
```

Suppose you do refactoring in a couple of months and rename your enumeration elements like _007 --> CMD_007, FOO --> CMD_FOO. Then after renaming the logic where _007 was used will still work, because it has code "007" which was not changed during refactoring. But renaming FOO --> CMD_FOO leads to the change of the code from "FOO" to "CMD_FOO". As if you have changed FOO("FOO") to CMD_FOO("CMD_FOO"). This can brake your logic. The worst here is, that you will see no compile errors and you will notice these problems much later during run time. I would recommend you to declare the codes explicitly.